# Html <form> tags , method and action explain

Tags: php, html

I can't actually understand how `method=` and `action=` works.
Could you please explain as for a beginner?

---

I read this:

> if the web server `www.example.com` has the document root in d:\site, and in this directory there is an `script.php` file, the client will acces the file via URL `http://www.example.com/script.php`

What is `script.php` in the `action="way/to/your/script.php"` syntax. If I don't have this file in the directory will it be created after submitting the request? (If yes , in which directory?)

Comment: In short the form is a way to communicate from the client to the server. If the server can't find the file in question an error will result.

Comment: You just tell the server where it should point to (the physical file, or a route if you're using a framework like Laravel) to handle the $_POST or $_GET request. That's all. If I call Tom I need Tom's phone number to reach him. It doesn't get any easier than that.

Comment: Everything you want to know can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Action doesn't create any scripts, doesn't create any files and doesn't make any actual changes on it's own. It's just the URL that you'll be sent to on submit. If your page is on http://test.com/test.php, and your action is `action="way/to/your/script.php"`, then you'll be sent to `http://test.com/way/to/your/script.php`. If that script doesn't exist, you'll get a `404` erorr.

As for the `method`, it's about *how* your data is sent. You can either send it over `GET`, which means all of your variables are sent in the URL it'self (and PHP will have to retrieve them through $_GET), while `POST` will send the data as a payload of the request itself, not in the URL. It's more secure and you can send more data. PHP will have to access this through `$_POST`

Comment: So If I had the script.php inside of it what should I find after a submit of a form which asks for your name and u împut your name into a text box?

Comment: script.php would then accepts the variables sent to it and do stuff with it

Comment: And I also forgot to ask you about Php self superglobal

Comment: There is no self superglobal. At this point you should be looking at reading tutorials on PHP

Comment: So I should find în script.php the post/get variabiles with the wanted values or they will be lost when redirecting to the web adress of the program that will do stuff with it?

Comment: I meant $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'']

Comment: Pretty much. Like I said, at this point you're looking for more a tutorial on PHP than the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

The action specifies the URL that the data will be sent to.

The method specifies if the data in the form should be encoded in the query string and the URL requested with GET or if it should be encoded in to the request body and the URL requested with POST.

*script.php* will be a program, written in PHP, that you put in a directory your webserver can access, just like any other resource. The server will need to be configured to treat it as a server side program instead of a static resource (this is the default for .php files on servers with PHP support). (This assumes you don't have any URL rewriting in play that might complicate things).

If you don't have anything on the server to handle that URL then you will get a `404 Not Found` error.